# How do I make TextBox Cursor/Caret a non-blinking Horizontal Line (underscore) instead of a Vertical Line (default)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

By default, a `TextBox` has a vertical blinking cursor/caret. By default, these cursors in text fields on this site (and most sites) are probably too.

If I want a non-blinking horizontal line (looking like a underscore `_` ), would that be possible?
I've read topics about editing the default vertical one to be colorful and even replaced with a image...but haven't come across a horizontal request.

I have played with the properties to make the vertical line almost look like a dot (gradient color choices). However, that seemed incredibly excessive just to (somehow) get a horizontal line.

---

#### This is my expectation:

```
Enter your text here __

This is text that has been entered, notice how the cursor/caret is still leading  __
```

#### This is what I have currently:

```
Enter your text here, the cursor is blinking |

This is text that has been entered, look at the boring cursor/caret leading us |
```

---

Is being excessive the only way?

For reference, this is what I played around with excessively: [Code Project - Customizing the Caret of a WPF TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox)

Using Visual Studio 2013 & 2013, if that makes any difference.

Comment: It sounds like excessive is the only way. Could you take the thick red vertical cursor from the link and change the size so it's a underscore shape?

Comment: There is a [CaretBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretbrush(v=vs.95).aspx) property of the TextBox. You should be able to do it using this and maybe an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @gunr2171 Good question. I'm not sure if you can change the height of the vertical cursor like you can the thickness. The only two properties that seem to effect the Caret are [CaretBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.caretbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CaretIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx)...and those are very specific to what they can do, as far as I know.

Comment: What about when you move the caret, make the Y position very low on the control?

Comment: @gunr2171 Interesting idea. If the position doesn't inadvertently effect the position of the text itself, and gets cut off by the bounding box around the TextBox...it might work (with respect to making the caret look thicker). I'll play around with that and see if it yields a "less-than-excessive" result. :)

Comment: @icemanind If you use an ImageBrush, it still only shows a vertical line (it looks like it take a vertical slice from the ImageSource)

Comment: @gunr2171 Nothing special with messing with the `CaretIndex`, just changes the insertion point...which seems like where text will be inserted. :(

Comment: @Jane - Can't you make an image that looks like an underscore, then use ImageBrush to set the image to that underscore Image?

Comment: Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6db60b7d-d418-41a9-ab77-3cc43bcec4c2/draw-caret-in-textbox-as-underscore?forum=wpf

Comment: Just an update, I haven't got luck with getting a working underscore-looking caret. :(